# Squeel query syntax to retrieve users' elements sharing the same group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel, squeel

Using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and Squeel I have the following models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :characters, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Characters have a boolean attribute `:public`.

Within the Character model, I want to retrieve all characters that are visible to the current user, as determined by the following conditions:

1. The character belongs to the current user OR
2. The character is public OR
3. The current user shares a group with the character's user

The result has to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Matching the first two conditions is simple enough:

```
def self.own_or_public user_to_check
  where{
    (user_id == user_to_check.id) |
    (public)
  }
end
```

For the third condition the following query yields the correct results, but is probably not the best way to do it:

```
def self.shares_group_with user_to_check
  user_groups = Group.joins{users}.where{users.id == user_to_check.id}
  joins{user.groups}.
    where{
      user.groups.id.in(user_groups.select(id))
    }.uniq
end
```

Furthermore, I cannot find a way to concatenate the two results yielding an `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing the results from both queries (`merge` yields elements that match both queries, and `+` returns an `Array` instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation`).

Any help on how to handle this in one single Squeel query is much appreciated.

Comment: Gosh, got a tumbleweed for this: No one knows, no one cares...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try restructuring you problem a little and replace the `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations with `has_many, through` associations, and we will add another `has_many, through` association on the `Character` model as follows:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :groups, through: :memberships
    has_many :characters
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :groups, through: :user
end
```

The `Membership` model is the representation of the relationship between a `User` and a `Group` - essentially the join table that is hidden when using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I prefer to see the relationship (especially if it is important).

We also have an association on the `Character` model to the `Group`s associated with the user. This is helpful when we try to join our scopes.

Fleshing the `Character` model out, let's add the following:

```
sifter :by_user do |user|
  user_id == user.id
end

sifter :public do
  public
end
```

Using the sifters as our building blocks, we can add the following to get the *visible* characters (as you defined it) with:

```
def self.get_visible(user)
    Character.uniq.joins{groups.outer}.where{(sift :public)|(sift :by_user, user)|(groups.id.in(user.groups))}
end
```

This method takes an instance of `User` and finds the following `Character`s:

- All public characters.
- All the user's characters.
- All characters that belong to the user's groups.

And then we only take the distinct list of characters from those sets.

From rails console:

```
irb(main):053:0> Character.get_visible(User.find(4))
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Group Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "groups"."id" = "memberships"."group_id" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 4
  Character Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "characters".* FROM "characters" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "characters"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "memberships" ON "memberships"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "memberships"."group_id" WHERE ((("characters"."public" OR "characters"."user_id" = 4) OR "groups"."id" IN (2)))
[
    [0] #<Character:0x00000005a16b48> {
                :id => 4,
           :user_id => 4,
              :name => "Testiculies",
        :created_at => Tue, 13 Aug 2013 14:35:50 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Tue, 13 Aug 2013 14:35:50 UTC +00:00,
            :public => nil
    },
    [1] #<Character:0x00000005d9db40> {
                :id => 1,
           :user_id => 1,
              :name => "conan",
        :created_at => Mon, 12 Aug 2013 20:18:52 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Tue, 13 Aug 2013 12:53:42 UTC +00:00,
            :public => true
    }
]
```

To find all characters a particular `User` has, add an instance method to the `User` model:

```
def get_visible_characters
  Character.get_visible(self)
end
```

I think that will get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. There are two gotchas, however: The `distinct` scope yields an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`error and I replaced the `joins{groups}` with `joins{groups.outer}`to get own characters when user is not in a group. Need some more tests, but without the `distinct`scope it seems to work with the sifters.

Comment: The distinct scope works for me using Postgres, but I'm going to edit the answer and use `uniq` instead. Does that work for you? And good catch on the outer join to groups.

Comment: I did some more testing, and everything is working fine. Even without the `uniq`. So thanks again for your answer, much appreciated.